# Possibility of Time Travel?

Tags: time-travel

Is [time travel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel) still considered as a possibility? What does the newer theories like string theory, M theory, etc. say about it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7823/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Well, 2 years have passed since that question, something fundamental could theoretically have happened to change the answer :)