# Why could you not travel back in the time before a tipler cylinder is created?

Tags: spacetime, time-travel

Is it because the lightcones are not tipped all the way over in which the time axis points downwards?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is time travel possible? Is it possible to go back in time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2166/)

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, the answers to the linked question do cover time travel before the invention of such a machine as the [Tipler cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipler_cylinder).

Comment: @KyleKanos: I'm not sure any of the answers to the proposed duplicate really address the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to the Tipler cylinder being created all the light cones point upwards. So if you attempted to follow  time like path taking you backwards in time (that is backwards in the the time coordinate of the observer far from the cylinder) when you reached the time the cylinder was created you'd have to stop. At this point all light cones point upwards so your timelike path would move in the direction of increasing coordinate time again.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you know if R. Mallet's time machine that can only go back to the moment it was turned on an example of a Tipler cone?

I guess I answered my own question.  Apparently, it's similar but different.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Mallett#Time_travel_research

Comment: If Mallet's idea works it too can only go back to the moment it's turned on.

Comment: What about this: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.7983.pdf

Comment: What about it? If there's a specific point in that paper you want to pick out why not ask a fresh question about it.

Comment: Where it explains the TARDIS bubble. It says time exists before the bubble meaning can you go back in time before the bubble exist?  Even though it is impractical (like other time machine ideas) it's pretty cool.