# Time Travel possibility and Paradoxes of The Past

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, causality, time-travel

can one travel back in time and if not so, what laws prevent time travel to the past. this is quite a challenge to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is time travel possible? Is it possible to go back in time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2166/)

Comment: If our's traveling speed is greater then Velocity of Light we can travel to past, but that is not possible due to law of relativity

Answer (score 1):

In special relativity the answer is simple: no, you can't (unless the universe is topologically strange).

For general relativity the answer is more complicated: it is possible to construct spacetimes with what are called 'closed timelike loops': curves which are timelike (ie where the curve lies within the lightcone of all points on it) and which are closed: the curve forms a loop.  And I am pretty sure you can also arrange things so that the curves are smooth enough to be physically sensible (ie they have no sharp corners).

Such a curve is fairly bad news, any point on such a curve is in its own future (and past).  In other words such a spacetime does allow you to travel into your own past.

So the question to answer is: *are such spacetimes physically plausible*?  In particular do they represent stable solutions without silly energy conditions, and could they arise from plausible initial conditions?

Now, my knowledge of this is seriously out of date (as in: more than twenty years out of date), but the situation then was that people strongly suspected that they were *not* physically plausible, in the sense that you could not arrive at such a solution from physically plausible initial conditions.  However, at the time, there was no really convincing proof of this.

Personally, I would be *extremely* surprised if such solutions are physical.  Indeed, if they turn out to be plausible in GR I would regard that as strong evidence that there is something wrong with GR (and I'm saying this as someone who has the field equations on a t-shirt!)