# Is this a way to go to the past?

Tags: special-relativity, thought-experiment, time-travel

I know that one can time travel to the past through wormholes. But what if I use special relativity for that. I mean, If one has to go to the future, he has to increse his velocity, but what about going to the past. I propose that if we increase the velocity of the surroundings of a system while keeping its velocity constant, should'nt we be able to travel to the past? [image: my implication is more specified in the image below.]

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please note that in Special Relativity, the relative speed of two systems w.r.t. each other is always the same from both sides. I would advise you to go a bit deeper in your study of Special Relativity and then think about the question again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is time travel possible? Is it possible to go back in time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2166/)

Answer (score 0):

The proper time, $ \tau $, perceived by an object moving at velocity $ v $ relative to some original system is $ \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} t $, where $ c $ is the speed of light and $ t $ is time as measured by the original system (assuming $ t = 0 $ implies $ \tau = 0 $ - in other words, our two objects define the same time to be $ 0 $ - if this weren't the case, we would be off by a constant additive term). Since $ v^2 $ is even under switches of sign in $ v $, changing direction (moving the universe relative to the object as opposed to the object relative to the universe is in effect moving the object in the opposite direction of the universe) will keep the time dilation the same (not negate it).

It's also worth pointing out that classical mechanics is the limiting case of special relativity for slow speeds. Since this obviously isn't true for classical mechanics, it can't be true in relativity for any speeds (including human-scale ones).

Comment: Why the downvote?