# Alcubierre warp bubble effect on gravity and space

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, faster-than-light, warp-drives

I read the question *[Faster-than-light communication using Alcubierre warp drive metric around a single qubit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23121)*, and these questions came to mind:

1. What kind of impact would an [Alcubierre warp bubble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) have on a local star's or planet's gravitational field?
2. Could an Alcubierre warp buble be used inside a solar system without altering the orbits of planets or the orientation of stars?
3. What would the effects be of a warp bubble in a planets atmosphere?

Comment: With respect to AlanSE's comment about strange consequences, see also [my unanswered question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46390/would-warp-bubbles-emit-gravitational-cerenkov-radiation-in-general-relativity)

Answer (score 1):

When Miguel Alcubierre proposed a "*warp drive*" solution resolving the prohibition in Einstein’s special relativity on traveling faster than light the problem turns out to be that anybody in the path of the incoming space ship gets **fried**.

That’s the conclusion of a group of University of Sydney physics students who have re-examined the maths of the Alcubierre drive, and found that when it decelerated below faster-than-light speeds, it would **emit gamma rays** sufficient to be seriously unhealthy to anybody waiting in the arrivals lounge.

Mathematically, it’s possible to create a bubble of space, with spacetime compressed in front of the bubble and expanded behind it; that bubble will do the traveling on behalf of the spacecraft it encloses, as it were. Inside the bubble, no faster-than-light prohibition is broken. But in the – for want of a better word – "*unbubbled*" universe, the Alcubierre region can follow a path between two points that allow it to apparently travel between them faster than light.

However, in this paper, Alcubierre overlooked what happens to ordinary matter that the warp-drive spaceship would encounter on its travels.

**Hitch-hiking matter becomes planet-killer**.

The problem is that the Alcubierre Drive spaceship is going to encounter matter during its trip: space is only nearly empty, not completely empty. Matter traveling towards the ship, the paper says, will become "*time locked*" with the ship. When the ship decelerates, these hitch-hikers are released from the bubble emitting huge amounts of energy as gamma rays and high-energy particles.

So for answer your question :  warp bubble in a planets atmosphere is propably not a good idea...

> [Link to original paper](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/03/04/killer_warp_drive/)

Comment: Would said matter be swept to the sides of the spaceship?

Comment: @Demetri : The matter is rather transformed into energy as gamma rays and high-energy particles at the opposite direction to the deceleration.