# Can interacting QFT be formulated in terms of the path integral or hamiltonian of a relativistic particle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, time, path-integral, antimatter, arrow-of-time

I read that free QFT need not be formulated in terms of fields. One can derive the same propagator as the path integral of the single free particle action $\int d{\tau} \eta _{\mu \nu} x^{•\mu}x^{•\nu}$, as long as one also allows paths that go backward in time.

More specifically, the propagator of free QFT is:

$$\int d^4p \frac{e^{-ipx}}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$

This is also equal to:

$$\int _0^{\infty} d\tau \langle x_2,t_2|e^{-iH\tau}|x_1,t_1\rangle$$

$H$ is $\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} + m^2 -i\epsilon$. This operator generates translations in proper time $\tau$. Then we integrate over $\tau$ to sum over all paths connecting the two spacetime points. Time is treated as just another co-ordinate, so backward-in-time paths are allowed. This calculation is also equal to the path integral of the free particle action.

This calculation also happens to equal $\langle 0|T(\phi(x),\phi(y))|0\rangle$, for a quantum field $\phi$. This "co-incidence" forms the basis of the quantised field forumation of QFT.

The above makes the "quantised  field" formulation of QFT seem like a mathematical trick, a co-incidence. Can interacting QFT also be thought of this way, or do we need quantised fields for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is anti-matter matter going backwards in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391/2451), [Anti-matter as matter going backwards in time? (requesting further clarification upon a previous post)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86988/2451)

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to describe interacting QFT in terms of a first-quantized language? Without referring to fields, but rather treating particles as the fundamental entities? If this is it, I suggest editing your question to make these aspects more clear, so to keep it distinct of the duplicate

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Thanks. I changed the title. I think the body of the post is very different from the body of the other post.

Answer (score 0):

Feynman originally though that this was possible, but it turns out that if you want to correctly reproduce Bose or Fermi statistics then closed loop diagrams are necessary.