# antimatter moving back in time

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, antimatter

This just blew my mind away!  I was watching a video about imagining the fourth dimension and the narrator said that little line.  Can some people elaborate on this.  Also please keep it simple not too complicated.  Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391/

Comment: Link to video??

Comment: @SachinShekhar http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MN4KC_zlW4g#start=0:00;end=9:22;cycles=-1;autoreplay=false;showoptions=false

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747866/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195238/226902