# Reverse entropy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, time-reversal-symmetry

I don't know much about entropy but all I know is the energy of a system tends to spread, more generally things tend to chaos. And entropy is not reversible, you can not stick a broken egg together.

So, my question is, Does anti-matter have reverse entropy?

If we have an egg made of anti-matter does it move backward in time? Does it go from broken to fixed? (I know it's a different concept but there is a connection between flow of time and flow of entropy.)

[I got this idea from the movie TENET and I think it makes sense]

edit: again, I don't know much about Feynman Diagrams but for example in this diagram, electron emits gamma ray and turns into a positron, but also goes back in time, which is kind of what I asked.
[image: Time reversal of positron in Feynman Diagram]

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195238/226902 "Does antimatter increase or decrease in entropy over time?", see also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103421/226902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is tempting to think that anti-matter is somehow strange and exotic, but this isn't the case. Indeed as discussed in my question [Identification of particles and anti-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81787/identification-of-particles-and-anti-particles) the labels *matter* and *anti-matter* are somewhat arbitrary. So the going in point is that matter and anti-matter are going to behave the same way when it comes to thermodynamics. The second law applies to both, and an anti-matter egg is not going to reassemble itself as time flows.

What has confused you is the often made but rather misleading statement that anti-matter is matter going backwards in time. This refers to the fact that matter and anti-matter are related by [T-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry), and it's misleading because anti-matter is not matter going backwards in time. The T-symmetry referred to is a mathematical operation not time travel.

Re the Feynman diagram, and the comment to it:

> for example in this diagram, electron emits gamma ray and turns into a positron, but also goes back in time, which is kind of what I asked.

Feynman diagrams are a graphical representation of an integral and they do not show an actual physical process. The arrows on the lines do not show the direction particles are moving, they are just labels to distinguish particles from anti-particles. The diagram **does not** show anything moving backwards in time.