# What it means that there is only one electron in universe?

Tags: electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

Could someone explain if this statement is and what could possible mean?

Comment: Read here: [One-electron universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe)

Comment: There is no difference between one electron or another. They are indistinguishable. This is the starting point of this idea.

Comment: Note that "the statement exists" and "the statement is true" are different things. This is cm important concept to study and understand, but that doesn't mean it's true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only one electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111427/)

Comment: A universe with only one electron wouldn't make any sense,so I suspect you have misunderstood whoever said something like that. What they probably meant was that one electron is exactly like another,so if you have seen one (metaphorically speaking) you have seen them all.

Comment: When such a statement is made my modern physicists, it is usually a poetic statement than a literal one. It means that all the electrons are particle-state "excitations" of the same electron field. So all the electrons in the universe have the exact same intrinsic properties. So, poetically, they are all one in their properties and "origin".