# Are antiparticles just particle-shaped holes?

Tags: antimatter

If particles are simply regions of space where certain quantum fields have non-zero divergence, are anti-particles simply the corresponding regions of opposite divergence?

This seems like the intuitive answer, especially when considering the process of annihilation.  I have heard before that anti-particles are analogous to particles moving through time in reverse, which seems to indicate that an annihilation event is just a point of symmetry in that (arguably, single) particle's history.  This analogy breaks down, however, when it comes to gravitation, since there seems to be no evidence of a negative-mass particle.

So what then is the meaning of an anti-particle, when their symmetry is preserved across certain fields, but not other?

Comment: Where did you read that particles "particles are simply regions of space where certain quantum fields have non-zero divergence"? A scalar field doesn't have divergence, but you still have particles. What's the problem with the definition of antiparticle: particle with opposite charge? Finally, you might like this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391/

Comment: I second jinawee in saying that the divergence thing is something I have not heard before either. Might you be imagining a view like [the Dirac sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_sea) for your hole/particle view?

Comment: I suppose I misstated that.  My experience in QM isn't that great.  What I meant was that charge is non-zero, which is still irreconcilable with gravitational charge (mass).  I could just be asking a bad question.  The links are much appreciated.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_sea . *This analogy breaks down, however, when it comes to gravitation, since there seems to be no evidence of a negative-mass particle.* There isn't a problem with gravity. The relativistic definition of mass is $m^2=E^2-p^2$. Although $E$ is negative, $m$ can still be positive. In any case, it's energy-momentum that's the source of gravitational fields, not mass. A hole in a negative-energy state behaves as a positive-energy state.

Comment: i don't seem to comprehend the first two lines of your ques . can you be more clear about what you already know about particles/antiparticles in terms of their quantum fields

Answer (score 2):

Quantum field theory does have particles that are merely divergences in fields, called [topological solitons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_defect), but none of the particles of the Standard Model can be understood in that way, as far as I know.

CPT, the symmetry that exchanges particles with their antiparticles, negates charges associated with odd-spin fields (such as electric charge, associated with the spin-1 electromagnetic field) but not charges associated with even-spin fields (such as mass, associated with the spin-2 gravitational field). This is related, I think, to the 360°/s rotational symmetry of spin-s fields, but I don't understand it in any detail.