# Antiparticles as "holes" of the quantum fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

If particles are simply regions of space where certain quantum fields have non-zero divergence, are anti-particles simply the corresponding regions of opposite divergence?

This seems like the intuitive answer, especially when considering the process of annihilation. I have heard before that anti-particles are analogous to particles moving through time in reverse, which seems to indicate that an annihilation event is just a point of symmetry in that (arguably, single) particle's history. This analogy breaks down, however, when it comes to gravitation, since there seems to be no evidence of a negative-mass particle.

So what then is the meaning of an anti-particle, when their symmetry is preserved across certain fields, but not other?

Comment: Someone (I can't remember if it was you) posted a [nearly identical question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129613/are-antiparticles-just-particle-shaped-holes) earlier today, then deleted it, which had the effect of deleting all responses. If you want to make minor changes to a question, just edit it.