# Should the energy density of the vacuum be zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, vacuum

According to [Dark Energy and the Accelerating Universe](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March08/Frieman/Frieman5.html) quantum field theory says that the energy density of the vacuum, $\rho_{vac}$, should be given by
$$\rho_{vac}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\rm fields}g_i\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt{k^2+m^2}\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\approx\sum_{\rm fields}\frac{g_i k^4_{max}}{16\pi^2}$$
where $g_i$ is positive/negative for bosons/fermions and $k_{max}$ is some momentum cutoff.

My question is why do we only take the positive square root terms?

According to the [Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153415/feynman-stueckelberg-interpretation) a positive energy antiparticle going forward in time is equivalent to a negative energy particle going backwards in time. Maybe we cannot rule out negative energy virtual particles moving backwards in time?

Therefore, in order to include antiparticles in the above sum, maybe we should include the negative square root terms? If we do then we find that the energy density $\rho_{vac}=0$.

**Addendum** ok I accept that I was wrong - antiparticles have positive energy. But my original question still stands. Why do we ignore the negative energy modes in the above vacuum energy density calculation?

Comment: Both particles and anti-particles have energy $E=+\sqrt{\boldsymbol p^2+m^2}$. Anti-particles do **not** have negative energy.

Comment: Ok but why are the negative energy terms ignored in the vacuum energy density calculation?

Comment: Why do we ignore the negative energy modes in the above vacuum energy density calculation?

Comment: @JohnEastmond there's no such thing as "negative energy mode". There's negative *frequency* modes. Energy is a well-defined operator on the Fock space of the QFT, and its spectrum is bounded from below, meaning that **every single elementary particle contributes with positive energy**.

Comment: @JohnEastmond note that there's plenty of reasons to believe that the calculation above doesn't make much sense (not the last one is: the resulting prediction is off by some factor of $10^{120}$ from experimentally measured value, lol). But your explanation doesn't seem like one of them, sorry.