# Does reversing time give parity reversed antimatter or just antimatter?

Tags: antimatter, parity, time-reversal-symmetry, cp-violation, cpt-symmetry

Feynman's idea states that matter going backwards in time seems like antimatter.

But, since nature is $CPT$ symmetric, reversing time ($T$) is equivalent to $CP$ operation. So, reversing time gives parity reversed antimatter, not just antimatter.

What is happening here? Why does nobody mention this parity thing when talking about reversing time? What am I missing?

Comment: You're right, never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that antimatter is matter going back in time is usually associated with Feynman diagrams in QED, so we're talking about electrons, and electrons have parity +1, so:

$$ CPT = C1T = CT = 1 $$

So the parity part doesn't come into play, but it is required in general.

Answer (score 1):

Positrons have equal and opposite charge and parity to electrons. Hence when combined, they can produce a neutral gamma ray with no parity.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry

Comment: Oh, I get the problem now, after reading the first answer of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/is-anti-matter-matter-going-backwards-in-time Which also gives the explanation. Truly reversed, it is the same particle..!