# Is antimatter just matter inverted in an higher dimension?

Tags: antimatter, spacetime-dimensions, time-reversal-symmetry, arrow-of-time

This question arose in me after watching https://youtu.be/mmtLgYVEuJs?t=394. The link has a time in it so it takes you to the part I am talking about in the video.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Is anti-matter matter going backwards in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391/2451) and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think this is a duplicate I didn't say anything about time. Couldn't it be possible that there are more dimensions beyond just time? Did you watch the video?

Comment: What does "inverted in a higher dimension" mean?

Comment: @WillO see the video. It's a rotation through the higher dimension which is basically a parity transformation.

Comment: @JohnRennie A rotation and a parity transformation are unrelated sorts of transformation, so it's difficult to give any meaning to this. A rotation preserves the orientation of space, while a parity transformation inverses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "no", though it's an interesting question and there is more to it than this simple answer would suggest.

Matter and antimatter are related by a charge parity transformation, often abbreviated to $CP$. The charge transformation changes the sign of the charge, and the parity transformation is reflection in a mirror. So to change an electron into a positron you need to both change the charge from $-e$ to $+e$ and also swap the parity.

In the video you link the presenter shows how in two dimensions the letter R can be flipped by lifting it up out of the two dimensions and rotating it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is indeed a parity transformation, so it does the $P$ part, and it would also work with a 3D object lifted into a fourth spatial dimension and rotated. However it wouldn't turn matter into antimatter because the process does not do the charge transformation.

Comment: As for you last paragraph, this would be possible in any dimension: here you are looking for a rotation (determinant 1) in $\mathbb R^4$ that restricts to $(x,y,z,0)\mapsto (x,y,-z,0)$ (or any other element of $O(3)$ of determinant -1) on $\mathbb R^3 \times \{0\}$. This can be realized by moving through $(x,y,z,w)\mapsto(x,y,z\cos\alpha + w\sin\alpha, z\sin\alpha - w\cos\alpha)$

Comment: @doetoe Thanks, I'll update my answer :-)