What is the status of Wheeler’s ‘one-electron universe’ idea?
I'd like to ask the experts about the following:
Sometime ago, I read about the One-electron universe postulate by Wheeler, and I found the concept fascinating. I wonder if it is a line of work that is still being pursued, and whether an even bolder postulate can be made; namely, that all that we observe (ourselves included) comes from the interference of a single particle in an expanding cavity (our universe).
The way I understand it is this: I imagine a tiny “bowl”, a black body, where a burst of energy enters all at once. If there’s no external influence to maintain equilibrium, the container might crack or expand. In a cosmological context, this expansion could create space (and possibly time) inside it. The energy would then reflect within the expanding boundaries, causing interference patterns that evolve as the container grows.
These interference patterns could represent fields and particles, and as the system grows and interactions become more complex, denser structures could emerge, ultimately forming observable reality—background radiation, galaxies, and … life itself.
I find the repercussions of such an idea intriguing. Besides physics, one can think that it can potentially bridge science and spirituality. But, maybe the math and physics disagree, and this is what I'm looking forward to your thoughts about.
Some refs that I found from respective article on Wikipedia:

Feynman, Richard (1949). "The Theory of Positrons" ([PDF). Physical Review. 76 (6): 749–759.

Nambu, Yoichiro (1950). "The Use of the Proper Time in Quantum Electrodynamics I". Progress of Theoretical Physics. 5 (1): 82–94.


[I apologize in advance if this is not the typical technical question on Physics, and I hope it is still within topic. It is an honest question.]

I wonder … whether an even bolder postulate can be made. Personal speculations and non-mainstream physics are off-topic on this site. Please ask a question about mainstream physics. Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed.

I wonder if it is a line of work that is still being pursued. No.

Thanks Ghoster. Would you have a pointer that criticizes Wheeler's idea?

Can you please help me ask my question correctly? I don't know how to ask it in a way that satisfies your request.

Would you have a pointer that criticizes Wheeler's idea? No, but I have never met a single physicist who believes that all electrons and positrons are just one particle. That idea is of only historical interest.

I think a question like “What is the status of Wheeler’s ‘one-electron universe’ idea?” might be on-topic. You might get an answer explaining why it isn’t part of accepted physics.

What I'm saying is that what we call electrons and positrons are, maybe, different configurations with different properties which, however, originate from the same wave function. I don't think that you'd disagree with that.

In quantum electrodynamics, all electrons and positrons in the universe are quanta of a single quantum field (which is not the same thing as a wavefunction) pervading the universe. That’s entirely mainstream.

I see, I was using the wrong term and that created confusion. I should have used the term "quantum field" instead of "wavefunction". Got it, and I thank you. TIL

I believe that Wheeler was making a joke.

Feynman seems to have thought of the same, but in his Nobel speech says: "I did not take the idea that all the electrons were the same one from [Wheeler] as seriously as I took the observation that positrons could simply be represented as electrons going from the future to the past in a back section of their world lines. That, I stole!" – Feynman's Nobel Lecture

See the section “What is the main problem with one electron universe theory?” in this article. (Answer: Where are all the positrons?”)

Thanks Ghoster. Makes sense. You answered both questions in my post: Wheeler's idea of a single electron cannot hold in practice because of the observed baryon asymmetry. And, mainstream physics seems to follow a conceptual generalization of his idea with quantum fields where different kinds of particles emerge from a single quantum field. Finding the single quantum field from which all fields and particles can emerge is the goal of unified field theory. Thank you!

Different kinds of particles emerge from a single quantum field. A single quantum field describes one kind of particle, and its antiparticle. The Standard Model of particle physics has multiple quantum fields… 17 by one way of counting them.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391/2451 More on Wheeler's one-electron theory.
